# How to push notification to specific user using graphql and subscription in web?

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I am developing a website where there is specification for user level notification.

I tried to implement with Nestjs + graphql + subscription where i can create subpub and publish result, but i publish date its pushing for all users.
How to change to publish for particular user?